# How do I construct ajax request handling drop down change event in MVC 4 ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a bit of a scenario here using ASP.NET MVC 4. I have 2 dropdown lists whose contents are loaded via ViewBags within a controller. However, I want one to be loaded based on what is selected on another one above it (very simple when it comes to ASP.NET :D). Now I'm very new to MVC and was told I have to use ajax on different forums. The problem is that none of the snippets I customized for my use worked. Here is the controller code that should handle the Ajax request and the ajax script in the cshtml view that the drop downs are on:
First the View code:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserLevel)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserLevel, (SelectList)ViewBag.ListOfUserLevels)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserLevel)
    </div>
    <script type ="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#UserLevel").change(function () {
                var selection = $("#UserLevel").val();
                //var dataToSend = {
                //    value: selection
                //};
                //"XSAccount/SelectedIndexChanged"
                $.get({
                    url: '@Url.Action("SelectedIndexChanged", "Home")',
                value: $(this).val(),
                            success: function (data) {
                                //$("#output").text("server returned:" + data.agent);
                                ViewBag.ListOfUserGrades = data.grade;
                                var model = $('#UserGrade');
                                model.empty();

                                $.each(data, function (register, grade) {
                                    model.append("<option value='" + grade.label + "'>" + grade.value + "</option>");
                                });

                                //var str = "";
                                //str = "<select data-val='true' data-val-required='The User Grade field is required.' id='UserGrade' name='UserGrade'>";
                                //for (j = 0; j < data.grade.length; j++) {
                                //    item = data.grade[j];
                                //    //str += "<option value = " + item + ">" + item + "</option>";
                                //    model.append("<option value='"+ item + "'>" + item + "</option>");
                                //}
                                //str += "</select>";

                                //usergrade.innerHTML = str;

                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
    </script>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserGrade)
    </div>
    @{
        if (ViewBag.ListOfUserGrades == null)
        {
            ViewBag.ListOfUserGrades = new SelectList(new List<string>() { "", ""});
        }
    }
    <div id ="usergrade" class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserGrade, (SelectList)ViewBag.ListOfUserGrades)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserGrade)
    </div>
```

Now for the Controller Code that handles the ajax request.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult SelectedIndexChanged(string value)
    {
        UserBL bl = new UserBL();
        var grades = new UserGradeBL();
        if (grades.RetrieveAll().Count == 0)
        {
            grades.CreateDefaults();
        }
        var source = grades.RetrieveAll().Where(g => g.UserLevel.Trim() == value.Trim());
        var list = new SelectList(source, "Grade", "Grade");
        ViewBag.ListOfUserGrades = list;

        //List<string> gradelist = new List<string>();
        List<myObj> gradelist = new List<myObj>();
        foreach (var item in source)
            gradelist.Add(new myObj() { label = item.Grade, value = item.Grade });

        var levels = new UserLevelBL();
        if (levels.RetrieveAll().Count == 0)
        {
            levels.CreateDefaults();
        }
        list = new SelectList(levels.RetrieveAll(), "Level", "Level");
        ViewBag.ListOfUserLevels = list;

        var types = new  UserTypeBL();
        if (types.RetrieveAll().Count == 0)
        {
            types.CreateDefaults();
        }
        list = new SelectList(types.RetrieveAll(), "Type", "Type");
        ViewBag.ListOfUserTypes = list;

        return Json(new { grade = gradelist  }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //return View();
    }
```

By the way it is inside a controller called HomeController. I have tried putting the script in a separate file in Scripts folder that comes with the MVC project and registerd it in App_Start folder file bundleConfig.cs as follows:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/dropdown").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/dropdown.js"));
```

And then I called the script in this view page at the bottom like this

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dropdown")
```

all to no avail. By the way, I am using VS2012 on Win 8. I hope I supplied all the necessary information. Thanks in advance for you help,

Comment: First I would highly recommend changing `SelectedIndexChanged` to something more useful. Where does this break down? Does the ajax execute? Can you put a break point inside of the `jsonresults`? Does it even get that far?

Comment: It does not get there at all. You know it happens asynchronously. I even put a break point.

Comment: If you're in debug mode that doesn't matter. If the javascript executing and it reaches your action it will still hit the break point. I would suggest using fiddler to see if there's any error messages and break point your javascript.

Comment: Hi Eonasdan, I used internet explorer with F12 and it is not showing any responses. I think the issue now is that the change event is NOT causing postback. How do I cause postback to the server so that I can use an ajax post request?

Comment: glad you got it worked out

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer. Funny enough it was very simple. Here is the script first:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#UserLevel").change(function () {
                  var model = $('#UserGrade');
                    model.empty();

                    $.getJSON('/Home/IndexChanged', { value:  $("#UserLevel").val() }, function(data) {
                        $(data.grade).each(function() {
                            $("<option value='" + this.value + "'>" + this.label + "</option>").appendTo(model);
                    });

                })
                .error(function () {
                    alert("replace operation failed");
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

This is the action in Home controller

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult IndexChanged(string value)
    {

        UserBL bl = new UserBL();
        var grades = new UserGradeBL();
        if (grades.RetrieveAll().Count == 0)
        {
            grades.CreateDefaults();
        }
        var source = grades.RetrieveAll().Where(g => g.UserLevel.Trim() == value.Trim());
        var list = new SelectList(source, "Grade", "Grade");
        ViewBag.ListOfUserGrades = list;

        //List<string> gradelist = new List<string>();
        List<myObj> gradelist = new List<myObj>();
        foreach (var item in source)
            gradelist.Add(new myObj() { label = item.Grade, value = item.Grade });

        ...
        return Json(new { grade = gradelist }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
       //return View();
    }
```

And that's it! Here is my source of info:
http://www.schwammysays.net/cascading-select-lists-with-mvc-and-jquery/